# Passing Gridview Row's ID to new webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has a column for an ID in my database - WorkHoursNotRecordID that I am trying to pass the value to a new webpage.  I can get all other values to pass to new webpage except for this ID.  In my SQL database, it is the primary key in the table.  I'm thinking I have some syntax wrong, but I cannot figure it out.  I'll try to just include code that has this WorkHoursNotRecordID.

In the Gridview webpage aspx:

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkHoursNotRecordID" 
      ItemStyle-Width="120px"
      SortExpression="Description" />
```

...

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TimeSQLConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT tblWorkHoursNotRecord.EmployeeName, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.BeginDateOff, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.EndDateOff, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.AllDay_YesNo, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.BeginTimeOff, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.EndTimeOff, tblEmployees.Login, tblCodesWorkNotRec.Description, tblWorkHoursNotRecord.WorkHoursNotRecordID FROM tblWorkHoursNotRecord INNER JOIN tblCodesWorkNotRec ON tblWorkHoursNotRecord.WorkCode = tblCodesWorkNotRec.WorkCodeID INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON tblWorkHoursNotRecord.Employee = tblEmployees.EmployeeID WHERE (tblEmployees.Login = @username) ORDER BY tblWorkHoursNotRecord.BeginDateOff DESC"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="username" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the Gridview webpage vb:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow
    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        'Change the cell index number as per your grid cell index
        Response.Redirect("TimeOffNoRequestEdit.aspx?BeginDateOff=" + row.Cells(1).Text.ToString() + "&EndDateOff=" + row.Cells(2).Text.ToString() + "&BeginTimeOff=" + row.Cells(4).Text.ToString() + "&EndTimeOff=" + row.Cells(5).Text.ToString() + "&AllDay_YesNo=" + CType(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), CheckBox).Checked.ToString() + "&WorkCode=" + row.Cells(6).Text.ToString() + "&Description=" + row.Cells(6).Text.ToString()) ', +"&WorkHoursNotRecordID=" + row.Cells(9).Text.ToString())

    End If

End Sub
```

In the new webpage's aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="wkid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the new webpage's vb Page_load:

```
        wkid.Text = Request.QueryString("WorkHoursNotRecordID").ToString()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Why is the code that concatenates `WorkHoursNotRecordID` in the `Response.Redirect` commented out?  Is it causing some sort of error?  I can't tell from your question what the problem is.

Comment: Shoot!  I sent the one with it commented out so that I could test out the other things.  It shouldn't be commented out.  So, from my code (with it not commented out - hehe), it should pass the value of the id?

Comment: Mark - thanks for making me look at something other than the code above.  It was the sequence of my code.  See post below.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in my coding.  I needed to put the code wkid.Text = Request.QueryString("WorkHoursNotRecordID").ToString() before code that I had ending if another field equaled a value.  Well, I kept picking the wrong rows to test, and the code was ending because it equaled the value.  Just swapped the sequence, and it worked.  Thanks for all your help!